# Enable Orchard module on all tenants without having to do so manually.

Tags: orchardcms

Currently running a site with 100+ tenants and have to manually enable all the modules. Is there a way to enable all modules in orchard across all my tenants without having to go to each site and click enable or use  manually use the command prompt. I am also having the same issue deploying contents to multiple site. my set up is unique to where i have different database for each tenants.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how I enable/disable features from my modules' migration classes. What you could do is create a command line implementation (inherit from DefaultOrchardCommandHandler) that will fan out your enable/disable module commands to all the tenants.

I'm not sure how the tenant system works in terms fo command line, i think you may have to launch a separate command line bin\orchard.exe session for each tenant. If that's the case you can do the fanning in a script that calls into bin\orchard.exe. If you can do tenant specific commands for different tenants from a single session of bin\orchard.exe, you can do the fanning inside your Commands class.

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

    public int UpdateFrom2() {
        var features = _moduleService.GetAvailableFeatures().ToDictionary(m=>m.Descriptor.Id, m=>m);

        DisableFeature(features, "TinyMce");
        EnableFeature(features, "TinyMceDeluxe");
        EnableFeature(features, "Contrib.Cache");
        EnableFeature(features, "WebAdvanced.Sitemap");

        return 3; 
    }

    private void DisableFeature(Dictionary<string, Orchard.Modules.Models.ModuleFeature> features, string featureId) {
        if (features.ContainsKey(featureId) && features[featureId].IsEnabled) {
            _moduleService.DisableFeatures(new string[] { featureId });
        }
    }

    private void EnableFeature(Dictionary<string, Orchard.Modules.Models.ModuleFeature> features, string featureId) {
        if (features.ContainsKey(featureId) && !features[featureId].IsEnabled) {
            _moduleService.EnableFeatures(new string[] { featureId });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No no, all commands on the command-line take a /t: optional parameter that can specify a specific tenant. Combine that with the ability for the CLI to run batches and you've got your answer.

Comment: @Bertrand, yup, that was already incorporated into my answer. That's why I was saying depending on whether or not the console Orchard sessions are specific to a tenant, you either do the fanning inside the Commands class, or from the command line.

Comment: Yes, and I was just answering the uncertainty :)

Comment: Bertrand, what do you know about Orchard anyway! :)